# How to convert screen space to world space?

Tags: camera, hlsl, fragment-shader

I have a shader that should do raymarching.

But I have problems converting the fragment's position to a worldspace coordinate.

This is my vertex shader:

```
VertexShaderOutput VS(VertexShaderInput input)
{
    VertexShaderOutput output;
    output.Position = float4(input.Position.xy*2,0.0, 1.0);
    float4 worldPos = output.Position;
    output.WorldPos = mul(worldPos, InverseViewProjection);
    output.UV = input.UV;
    return output;
}
```

`input.Position` in this case is a quad from `-0.5` to `0.5`, hence why I multiply it by 2.

In my pixel shader, I want to get the ray start position from `output.WorldPos`.

However, the shader outputs `WorldPos` as this:

```
x = -118.943700000, y = -25.704420000, z = 23.763410000
```

This is wrong, because the camera is at around

```
x = -3846 y = -810 z = 734
```

What am I doing wrong? I expected a world position, but it seems to be a screen space position?

Here is how I create my matrices (DirectX SimpleMath):

```
View = Matrix::CreateLookAt(WorldPosition, target, up);
Projection = Matrix::CreatePerspectiveFieldOfView(fov, w / (float)h, n, f);
ViewProjection = View * Projection;
ViewProjection.Invert(InverseViewProjection);
Projection.Invert(InverseProjection);
View.Invert(InverseView);
```

The game renders perfectly fine, So I am certain The View/Projection Matrices are not wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay after a lot of fiddling.
I needed to divide `xyz` with `w`:
Here is my Vertex Shader for a fullscreen quad;

```
VertexShaderOutput VS(VertexShaderInput input)
{
    VertexShaderOutput output;
    output.Position = float4(input.Position.xy,0.0, 1.0);
    float4 worldPos = output.Position;
    worldPos = mul(worldPos, InverseViewProjection);
    worldPos.xyz /= worldPos.w;
    output.WorldPos = worldPos;
    output.UV = input.UV;
    return output;
}
```